# On clicking component redirect to custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am practising react. I have some boxes displayed on UI and clicking on a particular box should open a page corresponding to that box. For e.g If a click on Box 1 it should open a page(another component) which displays text "Box 1 Clicked". Currently i am just able to log box id on console but don't know how to redirect. Below is my code.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import boxes from './data'
import Box from './Box'
import './style.css'

export default function App(props) {

  const [squares, setSquare] = React.useState(boxes)

  function toggle(id){
    console.log(id)
  }

  const squareElements = squares.map(sqaure => (
        <Box 
            key={sqaure.id} 
            id={sqaure.id}
            on={sqaure.on} 
            toggle={toggle}
        />
  ))

  return (
    <main>
        {squareElements}
    </main>
  )
}
```

**Box.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Box(props) {

    const styles = {
        backgroundColor : props.on ? "black" : "white"
    }


    return (
        <div 
            style={styles} 
            className='box'
            onClick={() => props.toggle(props.id)}
        ></div>
    )
}
```

This is the component which i want to display on clicking a box.

**BoxInfo.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function BoxInfo(props) {
    return (
        <h2>Clicked {props.id}</h2>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you give more context about what kind of page you're asking? Is it a new component to replace all your boxes?

Comment: @NickVu Yes. Edited my questions with more detail. I want to display BoxInfo Component

Comment: What do you mean by opening a page, if it is a new page, you need to use `react-router`. or if you want to render this component on the same page, you can set a state for the clicked box and render the component instead of `<main />`

Comment: @AhmedTarek can you give a code snippet how to do that on same page.

Comment: @Deveshjha check my answer for rendering the box info in the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render it on the same page depending on the selected box.

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import boxes from './data'
import Box from './Box'
import './style.css'

export default function App(props) {

  const [squares, setSquare] = React.useState(boxes)
  const [activeBox, setActiveBox] = React.useState()

  function toggle(id){
    setActiveBox({id})
  }

  const squareElements = squares.map(sqaure => (
        <Box 
            key={sqaure.id} 
            id={sqaure.id}
            on={sqaure.on} 
            toggle={toggle}
        />
  ))

  if(activeBox){
    return <BoxInfo {...activeBox} /> 
  }

  return (
    <main>
        {squareElements}
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: It is only printing "Clicked". I want to display the boxid too. How do i do that ? And if possible can you also give example using react router so i try both.

Comment: I have edited my answer by setting the state like that `setActiveBox({id})`

Comment: @Deveshjha here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-hamilton-twcf9d?file=/src/index.js). also, I recommend you to visit the official documentation of the `react-router` [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial)